# How to define multiple dietary restrictions in suitableForDiet field?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

In Schema.org, when defining structure for restaurant menu page, you can define dietary restrictions, for example: Vegan, LowFat, GlutenFree. But how can you define that a certain menu item belongs to numerous categories?

In the spec, on https://schema.org/suitableForDiet, it shows an example for a single dietary restriction per item:

```json
"suitableForDiet": "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet"
```

but I need something that is more close to array, like so:

```json
"suitableForDiet": [
                     "http://schema.org/LowFatDiet",
                     "https://schema.org/GlutenFreeDiet",
                     "https://schema.org/VeganDiet"
]
```

However I did not see an array as a part of the spec.
Any idea?